# Script doesn't work with simple arithmetic

Tags: javascript

that's part of my script:

```
var count = $(".sliderItem").length;
if (count < lp + 5)
{
    alert("bp4");
    var clips = count-l;
    alert("bp5");
}
```

so the problem is: 'bp4' is visible but 'bp5' not.

when I change `var clips = count-1;` to `var clips = 1;` it works fine.

Somebody have some idea?

Comment: what error are you getting ? what is `lp` ? and what is `count` initialised to ? and what is `l` ?

Comment: Is `count-l` a typo in the question, or is that your real code? If it's your real code, where is `l` defined?

Comment: Remember that you can set real breakpoints in JS by using Chrome's Inspector, or Firebug. You can then get a much better idea of what is going on.

Comment: It's real code. `lp` is a decimal value.

Comment: @MateuszRogulski what about `l` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `var clips = count-1;` in your code, you have `var clips = count-l;`.

Change the letter `l` (lower case L) to `1` in your code.

Comment: And set font in editor which makes easy to notice difference between 0 and O or l, 1 and I.